# A control thread suspends and resumes a group of worker threads

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

There is a control thread and a group of worker threads in process. The work mode likes this:
(1) All the worker threads and control thread are running;
(2) When control thread checks some condition changes, it suspends all worker threads;
(3) After checking all worker threads are suspended, the control thread modifies some contents in memory;
(4) After modifing, the control thread resumes all worker threads.
My questions are:
(1) In step 2 and step 4, how can control thread suspend and resume all worker threads? I consider using pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal, but it seems only OK for a control thread and a worker thread.
(2) In step 3, how can control thread check all worker threads are suspended? I consider using a counter, is there any good methods?

Comment: I can see a list of points, but no real question. What is it that you want and what have you tried already? But my suggestion is lookup message queues or/and pthread_cond_signal

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Thanks for your reply! The real thing I want is how to implement:A control thread suspends and resumes a group of worker threads. Your suggestion: lookup message queues or/and pthread_cond_signal. Could you explain detailedly?

Answer (score 1):

```
In step 2 and step 4, how can control thread suspend and resume all worker threads? I consider using pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal, but it seems only OK for a control thread and a worker thread.
```

You can assign priority to threads in pthread and you can assign higher priority to the control thread and schedule the control thread to work first and make the other threads wait .

```
 After checking all worker threads are suspended, the control thread modifies some contents in memory.
```

Is it as shared memory ? If its a shared memory you can have a mutex lock to allow one thread to access critical section at a time.

If you have a code that would be easy to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think it isn't the answer I want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to suspend threads? If I understand you correct, you are trying to solve [Readers writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem). In this case I'd recommend pthread_rwlock_t to provide an exclusive access to the shared memory for your control thread.